# Fast 2D array lookup of int16_t LUT using AVX2 or AVX512

Tags: c++, optimization, avx, lookup-tables, avx512

I would like to speed up an algorithm which performs a series of lookups in a 2D array. Basically it's like a matrix multiplication accessing both arrays in the same order but there is no multiplication, only look-up (probably B matrix is more efficient to be stored like that?). So the Look-up table is 256x256 with int16_t values and A,B matrices have int8_t values. Here is the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        int temp = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
            uint8_t a = A[i*K+k];
            uint8_t b = B[j*K+k];
            temp += lut[a][b];
        }
        C[i*N+j] = temp; 
    }
}
```

I know AVX can do parallel look-ups but I cannot find a way to do this in a large 2D matrix like 256x256. AVX512 is supported. Also, g++ is used and any other optimizations are welcome too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

AVX2 only has vgather for 32 and 64 bit, not any other types. Supposedly you could get it to work by changing your LUT to int, then use the compiler intrinsic _mm256_i32gather_epi32

I guess you could also keep the current sizes. However, then you have to manually wrangle your lookups into the appropriate format. Without some extensive ASM or use of intrinsics, this will be impossible. I guess something like this would work:

1. Load 8 bytes of A and B
2. Interleave the bytes into uint16 using VPUNPCKLBW
3. Zero extend into 8 ints using VPMOVZXBD
4. Use VPGATHERDD on the LUT. It has an explicit scale parameter. If you set this to 2, you can gather int16 values using misaligned accesses meant for ints. Use a fixed offset of -2. Then the lower 2 bytes per entry will be garbage. Make sure that at least 2 bytes before the LUT can be accessed without segfaults (read: Allocate [256*256+1], store the actual LUT at offset 1)
5. Use VPSRAD to shift out the 2 garbage bytes and sign-extend to int32
6. Do your vectorized sum
7. At the end of the inner loop, use horizontal addition to reduce the vector to a scalar

Yeah, I can see why the compiler is not able to do this. Also note that gather is often not significantly faster than multiple scalar accesses. However, it would work really well on a GPU (even Intel builtin) because these could use the texture unit for exactly this operation.

This implementation seems correct and about twice as fast as the original for large K in a quick benchmark I did on an Intel Coffee Lake. I wouldn't exactly call it readable, though.

```
#include <cstdint>
// using std::uint8_t, std::int16_t
#include <immintrin.h>
// using intrinsics up to AVX2

void lutmat(int M, int N, int K,
            const std::uint8_t* A,
            const std::uint8_t* B,
            int* C,
            const std::int16_t* lut)
{
    // this needs to be valid! lut[-1] must not segfault!
    const int* lut32 = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(lut - 1);
    for(std::ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        const std::uint8_t* Ai = A + i * K;
        for(std::ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            const std::uint8_t* Bj = B + j * K;
            __m256i sum8 = _mm256_set1_epi32(0);
            std::ptrdiff_t k;
            for(k = 0; K - k >= 16; k += 16) {
                // fetch 16 bytes per input matrix
                __m128i ak = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i_u*) (Ai + k));
                __m128i bk = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i_u*) (Bj + k));
                // interleave into 2 x 8 16 bit values. These are our indices
                __m128i interleaved_lo = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(bk, ak);
                __m128i interleaved_hi = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(bk, ak);
                // zero extend indices to 32 bit values
                __m256i extended_lo = _mm256_cvtepu16_epi32(interleaved_lo);
                __m256i extended_hi = _mm256_cvtepu16_epi32(interleaved_hi);
                // do unaligned gather of 32 bit values.
                // Valid bytes are in upper 2 byte per int due to the offset in lut32
                __m256i gathered_lo = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(lut32, extended_lo, 2 /*scale*/);
                __m256i gathered_hi = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(lut32, extended_hi, 2 /*scale*/);
                // sign-extend and remove garbage in lower 2 byte
                __m256i corrected_lo = _mm256_srai_epi32(gathered_lo, 16);
                __m256i corrected_hi = _mm256_srai_epi32(gathered_hi, 16);
                // add to 8 partial sums
                sum8 = _mm256_add_epi32(sum8, corrected_lo);
                sum8 = _mm256_add_epi32(sum8, corrected_hi);
            }
            if(K - k >= 8) {
                // single iteration using just 8 fetched values
                __m128i ak = _mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i*) (Ai + k));
                __m128i bk = _mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i*) (Bj + k));
                __m128i interleaved_lo = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(bk, ak);
                __m256i extended_lo = _mm256_cvtepu16_epi32(interleaved_lo);
                __m256i gathered_lo = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(lut32, extended_lo, 2);
                __m256i corrected_lo = _mm256_srai_epi32(gathered_lo, 16);
                sum8 = _mm256_add_epi32(sum8, corrected_lo);
                k += 8;
            }
            // reduce 8 to 4 partial sums
            __m128i low4 = _mm256_castsi256_si128(sum8);
            __m128i high4  = _mm256_extracti128_si256(sum8, 1);
            __m128i sum4 = _mm_add_epi32(low4, high4);
            if(K - k >= 4) {
                // single iteration using 4 fetched values
                __m128i ak = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(*(const int*) (Ai + k));
                __m128i bk = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(*(const int*) (Bj + k));
                __m128i interleaved = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(bk, ak);
                __m128i extended = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(interleaved);
                __m128i gathered = _mm_i32gather_epi32(lut32, extended, 2);
                __m128i corrected = _mm_srai_epi32(gathered, 16);
                sum4 = _mm_add_epi32(sum4, corrected);
                k += 4;
            }
            // reduce partial sums to 1 scalar sum
            __m128i high2  = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(sum4, sum4);
            __m128i sum2 = _mm_add_epi32(high2, sum4);
            __m128i high1  = _mm_shuffle_epi32(sum2, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,3,1,1));
            int sum = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(_mm_add_epi32(sum2, high1));
            // add the last few entries
            // we use a separate partial sum to avoid a dependency chain through
            // the reduction above
            int tail = 0;
            for(; k < K; ++k) {
                uint8_t a = Ai[k];
                uint8_t b = Bj[k];
                tail += lut[a * 256 + b];
            }
            C[i*N+j] = sum + tail;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AVX2 has gathered loads for 32 bit and 64 bit ints (vpgatherXX) as well as floats and doubles.

Comment: @PaulR thanks! I changed the text

Comment: Instead of trying to shuffle a wide load 4 different ways, probably best to do 128-bit or 64-bit loads to feed `vpmovzxbd` zero-extension into an `__m256i` or `__m512i` vector.  But then yes, your steps look reasonable.  If the LUT was known to be non-negative, zero-extension is cheaper than sign-extension of 16-bit into the 32-bit element.  For the shifts, you don't need variable shifts, just plain old `vpslld` and `vpsrad` by an immediate 16.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the note! I was also thinking that the sign extension might be faster if we gather with a fixed offset of -2 so that the valid 2 bytes are already in the upper half of the dword.

Comment: Oh yes, right.  IIRC there has been a previous SO question about 16-bit gathers, and I remember that `-2` single-shift idea coming up before.  As far as avoiding cache-line splits, crossing into the preceding cache line for index `0` is just as bad as crossing into the next line for index `31` relative to a 64-byte line, I guess.  Except it's easier to pad at the end of the LUT than at the start, to avoid reading into an unmapped page before than after.  (Either way it would make it touch an extra page, beyond the 256^2 x 2B = 128kiB.)

Comment: Hmm, I'd suggested `vpmovzxbd` loads, but actually we might want to `vpunpcklbw` to interleave bytes, then `vpmovzxwd`.  Since A[] and B[] are 8-bit indices, and the LUT is 256x256, `lut[a][b]` should use a linear offset of `(a<<8) + b`, i.e. just a concatenation of the two 8-bit indices.

Comment: Good edit.  The loop could be unrolled to use `unpacklo_epi8` and `unpackhi_epi8` to use both halves of 128-bit loads.  (I didn't think of that earlier).  In the hsum, I'd recommend `extracti128` instead of `f`, since this is integer data and we're already using AVX2 intrinsics.  Won't matter on most CPUs.  Also, `_mm_shufflelo_epi16` is maybe silly on AVX2 CPUs, maybe best to just use a simple 32-bit element shuffle like `_mm_shuffle_epi32(v, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,3,1,1))` which runs the same on AVX2 CPUs, and is more human readable, and makes clang's peephole optimization to `vmovshdup` more clear.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks again! I've made the suggested changes and unrolled the loop tail a bit for 8 at a time and 4 at a time.