# Can OpenMP's SIMD directive vectorize indexing operations?

Tags: c++, openmp, eigen, simd

Say I have an MxN matrix (SIG) and a list of Nx1 fractional indices (idxt). Each fractional index in idxt uniquely corresponds to the same position column in SIG. I would like to index to the appropriate value in SIG using the indices stored in idxt, take that value and save it in another Nx1 vector. Since the indices in idxt are fractional, I need to interpolate in SIG. Here is an implementation that uses linear interpolation:

```
void calcPoint(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& idxt,
               const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<short int, -1, -1>>& SIG,
               double& bfVal) {
    Eigen::VectorXd bfPTVec(idxt.size());
    #pragma omp simd
    for (int j = 0; j < idxt.size(); j++) {
        int vIDX = static_cast<int>(idxt(j));
        double interp1 = vIDX + 1 - idxt(j);
        double interp2 = idxt(j) - vIDX;
        bfPTVec(j) = (SIG(vIDX,j)*interp1 + SIG(vIDX+1,j)*interp2);
    }
    bfVal = ((idxt.array() > 0.0).select(bfPTVec,0.0)).sum();
}
```

I suspect there is a better way to implement the body of the loop here that would help the compiler better exploit SIMD operations. For example, as I understand it, forcing the compiler to cast between types, both explicitly as the first line does and implicitly as some of the mathematical operations do is not a vectorizable operation.

Additionally, by making the access to SIG dependent on values in idxt which are calculated at runtime I'm not clear if the type of memory read-write I'm performing here is vectorizable, or how it could be vectorized. Looking at the big picture description of my problem where each idxt corresponds to the same "position" column as SIG, I get a sense that it should be a vectorizable operation, but I'm not sure how to translate that into good code.

**Clarification**

Thanks to the comments, I realized I hadn't specified that certain values that I don't want contributing to the final summation in idxt are set to zero when idxt is initialized outside of this method. Hence the last line in the example given above.

Comment: I'd expect GCC or clang's normal vectorizer to be able to use AVX2 or AVX512 gather loads, if you compile with `-O3 -march=haswell` or later.  (Or `-march=skylake` where they're actually fast, not earlier Intel or AMD).  IDK about the OpenMP vectorizer; for GCC it's apparently different.  Although either way, it would have to prove that stores into `bfPTVec` can't alias with indices loaded from `idxt`, i.e. to prove that its stores aren't getting reloaded as indices in the next few iterations.

Comment: You can explore this on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/s9j7q458d). The expectations of @PeterCordes seem to be right: When specifying the skylake architecture and compiling without OpenMP the code gets vectorized for both gcc trunk and clang trunk. With OpenMP activated, gcc gives different, but still vectorized code, but clangs implementation of OpenMP seems to fail. You can spot vector instructions by the `v` prefix, like `vmulsd`.

Comment: @PaulG.: Note that `vmulsd` is Scalar Double.  What you're actually looking for is use of YMM 256-bit registers, or XMM with `pd` instructions.  (If you don't enable (a CPU with) AVX, legacy SSE instructions don't start with v.  Like `addpd` is 2-wide packed-double).

Comment: @PaulG.: Yeah, looks like even with `-march=skylake` without OpenMP, only `((idxt.array() > 0.0).select(bfPTVec,0.0)).sum()` gets vectorized.  (In a *very* poor way without `-ffast-math`, otherwise it unpacks the masked vector load and does a sequence of scalar adds.  But goodish with `-ffast-math` https://godbolt.org/z/cj4Wxe5or, looks like it redundantly uses both `vmaskmovps` masked loads and `vandpd` with the same mask it used to do the zero-masked load. 
 Then only hsum that ymm outside the loop.)

Comment: @PaulG. Unfortunately GCC, Clang and ICC all fail to generate a proper SIMD code. With some help and code change (see the answer), they partially succeed, but the generated code of GCC/Clang is not efficient... ICC succeed to use gather instructions but it appear to fail to inline some Eigen functions in the hot loop (for no apparent reasons)...

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the correction. I should have trusted the hover-over text.

Comment: You can get gather instructions if you replace all types (except the index) by `float` and avoid the temporary vector and the `idxt.array() > 0.0` masking. (That is where I stopped playing around, feel free to check how much you can change back ...): https://godbolt.org/z/qE15T1zo4

Comment: Maybe transpose the input? BTW, are the indices arbitrary, or is there some kind of pattern -- if the indices are very close to each other, then I would try to read 16 x int16_t, deinterleave to even and odd streams and `vshufb`. Just as a side note, there's a huge precision difference of the values that need to be interpolated -- is a double really required to interpolate between 16-bit values?

Comment: Implementing the float approach that @chtz suggested strangely enough seemed to slow down my code. I didn't look too deeply into it since I had to implement the conditional outside my function call, but I suspect this has something to do with other parts of my code that could be poorly written and not chtz' approach. Still, I thought I'd comment that I tried that in case anyone else comes digging here in the future...

Comment: @drakon101 I did not bother to provide a manually vectorized solution -- looking up two adjacent `int16_t` would actually be quite nice, since they can be gathered at once (and the automatically generated solution is clearly sub-optimal). If 15 or 16 bit precision for the linear interpolation is sufficient, you could directly use this as one input of a `vpmaddwd`. The `idxt.array() > 0.0` as-is is almost useless, since for negative values the look-up in `SIG` is undefined (it will assert in non-debug builds), i.e., it only makes a difference for values between `-1` and `0`.

Comment: Ah I realize I didn't specify in the body of my question, but when idxt is initialized in a different function, values that don't meet a certain condition (lets call that condition 'X') are set equal to zero. Therefore, in this function, the idxt values that don't meet condition 'X' don't contribute to the final sum.

Comment: You should probably insert checking that condition as well as the summation inside the main loop (avoiding the temporary `bfPTVec`). Also, you never clarified whether you actually need `double` precision for `idxt` and the sum.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about double precision yet. It is possible I do need it, so I've kept it as double precision for now. It would be hard to explain why without going outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I wrote some code for vectorized indexing of 16 bit ints some time ago. I could adapt it to your problem if you still pursuit this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69797134/fast-2d-array-lookup-of-int16-t-lut-using-avx2-or-avx512/69797302#69797302

Comment: Extra implementations are always helpful and would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably no, but I would expect manually vectorized version to be faster.

Below is an example of that inner loop, untested. It doesn’t use AVX only SSE up to 4.1, and should be compatible with these Eigen matrices you have there.

The `pIndex` input pointer should point to the j-th element of your `idxt` vector, and `pSignsColumn` should point to the start of the j-th column of the SIG matrix. It assumes your SIG matrix is column major. It’s normally the default memory layout in Eigen but possible to override with template arguments, and probably with macros as well.

```
inline double computePoint( const double* pIndex, const int16_t* pSignsColumn )
{
    // Load the index value into both lanes of the vector
    __m128d idx = _mm_loaddup_pd( pIndex );

    // Convert into int32 with truncation; this assumes the number there ain't negative.
    const int iFloor = _mm_cvttsd_si32( idx );

    // Compute fractional part
    idx = _mm_sub_pd( idx, _mm_floor_pd( idx ) );
    // Compute interpolation coefficients, they are [ 1.0 - idx, idx ]
    idx = _mm_addsub_pd( _mm_set_sd( 1.0 ), idx );

    // Load two int16_t values from sequential addresses
    const __m128i signsInt = _mm_loadu_si32( pSignsColumn + iFloor );
    // Upcast them to int32, then to fp64
    const __m128d signs = _mm_cvtepi32_pd( _mm_cvtepi16_epi32( signsInt ) );

    // Compute the result
    __m128d res = _mm_mul_pd( idx, signs );
    res = _mm_add_sd( res, _mm_unpackhi_pd( res, res ) );
    // The above 2 lines (3 instructions) can be replaced with the following one:
    // const __m128d res = _mm_dp_pd( idx, signs, 0b110001 );
    // It may or may not be better, the dppd instruction is not particularly fast.

    return _mm_cvtsd_f64( res );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried implementing this function, but I'm getting a strange error saying that _mm_loadu_si32 is not declared in this scope. I'm importing immintrin.h and I tried also changing the type of pSignsColumn to const int*, but nothing seemed to work. Googling the command led to some results that indicated there were implementation issues with older versions of gcc, but I'm not really understanding what I'm finding. Do you have any suggestions for alternate commands that could work for that line?

Comment: @drakon101 Sure. `#define _mm_loadu_si32(p) _mm_cvtsi32_si128(*(const int*)(p))`

Comment: Wow all of this worked quite well. I got a ~1.8x speedup with these SSE2/SSE3 instructions alone. I'm going to take this approach and try writing an avx2 and avx512 version and share it as a reference later, but thanks for the feedback!!

Comment: @drakon101 Yeah, that’s what I would expect. My version uses about twice as few instructions because `__m128d` vectors for double arithmetic, and 2/3 of memory loads because it uses a single 32-bit load to fetch both `int16_t` values. AVX2 version is possible with `_mm256_i32gather_epi32`, but _way_ more complicated. Ideally, you gonna need to manually unroll by a factor of 8 handling the remainder with different version, and inside that manually unroll yet again by factor of 4 because AVX only has 4-wide vectors of FP64 lanes.

Comment: @drakon101 Also, be sure to test with the commented out `_mm_dp_pd` version. The latency is not great, but the throughput is not too bad on modern processors.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, it *should be possible*, assuming the processor support this operation. However, in practice, this is not the case for many reasons.

First of all, mainstream x86-64 processors supporting the instruction set AVX-2 (or AVX-512) does have instructions for that: [gather SIMD instructions](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=AVX2&text=_mm256_*gather). Unfortunately, *the instruction set is quite limited*: you can only fetch 32-bit/64-bit values from the memory base on 32-bit/64-bit indices. Moreover, this instruction is not very efficiently implemented on mainstream processors yet. Indeed, it fetch every item separately which is not faster than a scalar code, but this can still be useful if the rest of the code is vectorized since reading many scalar value to fill a SIMD register manually tends to be a bit less efficient (although it was surprisingly faster on old processors due to a quite inefficient early implementation of gather instructions). Note that is the `SIG` matrix is big, then *cache misses* will significantly slow down the code.

Additionally, AVX-2 is not enabled by default on mainstream processors because not all x86-64 processors supports it. Thus, you need to *enable AVX-2* (eg. using `-mavx2`) so compilers could vectorize the loop efficiently. Unfortunately, this is not enough. Indeed, most compilers *currently fail to automatically detect* when this instruction can/should be used. Even if they could, then the fact that IEEE-754 floating point number operations are not associative and values can be infinity or NaN generally does not help them to generate an efficient code (although it should be fine here). Note that you can tell to your compiler that operations can be assumed associated and you use only finite/basic real numbers (eg. using `-ffast-math`, which can be unsafe). The same thing apply for Eigen type/operators if compilers fail to completely inline all the functions (which is the case for ICC).

To speed up the code, you can try to change the type of the `SIG` variable to a matrix reference containing `int32_t` items. Another possible optimization is to split the loop in small fixed-size chunks (eg.32 items) and split the loop in many parts so to compute the indirection in a separate loops so compilers can vectorize at least some of the loops. Some compilers likes Clang are able to do that automatically for you: they generate a fast SIMD implementation for a part of the loop and do the indirections use scalar instructions. If this is not enough (which appear to be the case so far), then you certainly need to vectorize the loop yourself using SIMD intrinsics (or possible use SIMD libraries that does that for you).